# Is there a way to include jade file directly in html file?

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

How can I combine a node.js website that its frontend is based on html with another node.js website that its frontend is based on jade template engine?  I am using Express framework.

On the frontend there are four files: `index.html, index2.html, chat1.html, chat2.html`, which are located in the public folder.  The blog website that I want to add to this website has only `jade template engine`, which are located in the views folder.

The `index.html` (which is in public folder) is the entry point to the home page of the website.  When from `index.html` I refer to `index3.jade`, which is the Home page of the second app, i.e., blog jade app, Chrome browser states: "404 Not Found".  However, I can go to the other two pages of the blog jade website, i.e., Add Post and Add Category.  It is only the Home page of the blog jade app that is not being displayed.

So, I am not able to see only the Home page of the blog jade app, which starts at the root directory.  Both the html app and the blog jade app start at the root directory.  I was able to make the blog jade app to be displayed at the root directory, but then I could not see the html app, which also starts at the root directory.

Here is how I referred to each file from index.html front page:

```
`<li><a href="index2.html">gallery</a></li>`
`<li><a href="chat1.html">chat</a></li>`
`<li><a href="../views/index3.jade">blog</a></li>`
```

Is there a way to have the home page of the blog jade app to be displayed at a directory other than the root directory?

Here is the related app.js code:

```
// Gallery HTML Code
var routes = require('./');
app.get('/public/index.html');

// Blog Code
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

var routes = require('./');
var routes = require('./routes/index3');
var posts = require('./routes/posts');
var categories = require('./routes/categories');

var app = express();

app.locals.moment = require('moment');

app.locals.truncateText = function(text, length) {
    var truncatedText = text.substring(0, length);
    return truncatedText;
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
        var namespace = param.split('.'),
            root = namespace.shift(),
            formParam = root;

        while (namespace.length) {
            formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
        }
        return {
            param: formParam,
            msg: msg,
            value: value
        };
    }
}));

// Connect-Flash from Express-Messages
app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
    next();
});

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/index3', routes);
app.use('/posts', posts);
app.use('/categories', categories);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
       res.status(err.status || 500);
       res.render('error', {
           message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
       message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Here is the related code from index3.js in the routes folder:

```
router.get('index3', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var posts = db.get('posts');
    posts.find({}, {}, function(err, posts) {
        res.render('index3', { posts: posts });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the related code from index.js in the routes folder:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('public/index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I believe that the blog app has a route handler which renders index3.jade. can you show some code of the blog app. app.js, server.js or routes.js could be files where the routes are defined.

Comment: Hi Molda, Thank you for your help.  I just converted all of my html files to jade, still I am having the same problem.  So the problem is apparently with routing, i.e., two apps cannot be in the same root route.  Here are some code from app.js `var routes = require('./');`
`var routes = require('./routes/index3');`
`var posts = require('./routes/posts');`
`var categories = require('./routes/categories');`  I try to add app.js and index3.js codes on the question itself.

Comment: When I added an authentication app, similarly the root directory of the second app does not show.  So the problem is how to adjust the code in express router, views folder for jade files of the second app, public folder for files of the first app, and going from the first app to the root directory of the second app.  When I go to the root directory of the second app `<li><a href="../views/index3.jade">blog</a></li>`, I get `404 not found` at the root directory.  The root directory of the second app runs only from the root, not `index3.jade`

Comment: First thing i noticed is that you have `var routes = require('./');` and just bellow you overwrite `routes` with `var routes = require('./routes/index3');` that's kinda wierd :)
Now when you define `router.get('index3'..` and use it like this `app.use('/index3'..` the url needed to access this endpoint is `example.com/index3/index3` so your link `<a href="../views/index3.jade">` should be `<a href="/index3/index3">` so i recommend to use `app.use('/blog',routes);` and in index3.js use `router.get('/',...` this way the link should be `<a href="/blog">` and you should get index3.jade rendered.

Comment: It did fix everything.  Thank you very much, you saved me from a lot of frustration.  Regarding, the code `var routes = require('./');` which is being  overwritten by `var routes = require('./routes/index3);` I tried to change it, but it messes up everything, so I left it as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by *it messes up everything*. Just remove this line `var routes = require('./');` it shouldn't mess up anything.

Comment: I removed `var routes = require('./');` and it works fine.  As far as I checked, it is perfect. Now I plan to add authentication app to it.  When I said it messed up everything, I meant when I changed `var routes = require('./routes/index3);` to `var index3 = require('./routes/index3);` I got an error message in Git Bash.